# Tkinter: Adding drop downs dynamically and getting their values

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am adding drop downs dynamically based on user input. The user will input a title. Each word in the title has a list of synonyms associated with them. Tkinter will add drop downs of synonyms dynamically based on the user input. However I cannot individually access the value of each drop down.

The lists variable is a list of lists containing the synonyms for each word in the user input.

```
def ok():
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())

 i = 0
    while i < len(lists):

        OPTIONS = lists[i] 

        OPTIONS = OPTIONS.split(',')

        variable = StringVar(master)

        dropdown = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
        dropdown.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=YES)

        button = Button(master, text="Swap", command=ok)
        button.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)

        i = i+1
```

Is there a way I can access the value set from my drop downs?

Comment: every `OptionMenu` need own `variable` - but you use only one `variable` for all  `OptionMenu`

Comment: instead of `while i < len(lists): OPTIONS = lists[i]` you can use `for OPTIONS in lists:` and it doesn't need `i`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I access the variables individually?

Comment: Also how would I give each drop down its own variable?

Comment: in code I see `variable` . how did you create it ? do you know how to keep elements on list ? So keep variables on list.

Comment: you can also use `command=lambda var=variable: ok(var)` in `Button` and `def ok(var)` and when you click button then function will get variable

Comment: you can also use `OptionMenu(..., command=ok)` and `def ok(text)` and it will run function (with selected text) when you change selection.

Comment: Apologies I am quite new to python. I am still quite confused about the list of variables. How would I take into account your suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191795/discussion-between-gavin-fitzpatrick-and-furas).

Comment: `all_variables.append(variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `command=` in `OptionMenu` you can assign function which will get selected value when you change selection.

```
import tkinter as tk

#--- functions ---

def on_select(text):
    print('text:', text)
    print('---')

#--- main ---

data = ['a,b,c', 'x,y,z']

root = tk.Tk()

for i, options in enumerate(data):
    options = options.split(',')
    op = tk.OptionMenu(root, tk.StringVar(), *options, command=on_select)
    op.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`command=` in `Button` expected function which doesn't get parameters - ie. `def on_select():` but `command=` in `OptionMenu` expects function which gets single parameter - ie. `def on_select(text):`

This code doesn't need `variable = tk.StringVar()`

---

So you have selected value but you don't know in which `OptionMenu` it was selected - in first or second. Using `lambda` you can assign function which will get more parameters and you can put number as second parameter.

```
import tkinter as tk

#--- functions ---

def on_select(text, number):
    print('text:', text)
    print('number:', number)
    print('data[number]:', data[number])
    print('---')

#--- main ---

data = ['a,b,c', 'x,y,z']

root = tk.Tk()

for i, options in enumerate(data):
    options = options.split(',')
    op = tk.OptionMenu(root, tk.StringVar(), *options, command=lambda text, number=i:on_select(text, number))
    op.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So now first OptionMenu runs `on_select(text, 0)` and second runs  `on_select(text, 1)` so function knows which OptionMenu was selected and it can get correct values from data (or do other things)

---

You can also use `StringVar()` to get selected values. if you need all selected values then you have to create separated `StringVar` for every `OptionMenu` and keep on list. When you click button then you can use `for` loop with list of variables to get all selected values.

```
import tkinter as tk

#--- functions ---

def on_click():
    for number, var in enumerate(all_variables):
        print(number, '| selected:', var.get(), '| all:', data[number])

#--- main ---

data = ['a,b,c', 'x,y,z']

root = tk.Tk()

all_variables = []

for options in data:
    options = options.split(',')
    var = tk.StringVar()
    all_variables.append(var)
    op = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *options)
    op.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That has worked for me! However when I select an item from my drop down, the default value for the drop down does not change. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: what default value ? if you need to select some value at start then you `StringVar(value=options[0])`